# Load multiple data files into multiple tables using single control file using sql loader

Tags: oracle, shell, sql-loader

I have requirement to load billions of record into 5 different tables , each one of these tables have different data files. These 5 tables will be populated daily and will be truncated next day before loading fresh data.

- Que1 : How do I load data into 5 different table using 5 different data files using 1 control fle?
- Que2: Do I need 5 different discard, log and bad files to keep track of these 5 different loads?
- Que3 : What is better and efficient way to load billions of records daily - using 5 different control table , 5 discard ,5 log file OR just 1 control table will solve the purpose.
- Que4: What if one of 5 load fails then I need to rerun the sqloader for all 5 tables again?

Note : As of now we are loading data into one table but it is taking 5-6 hours to load, so we are looking for better performance. 
I will be running sqlldr from shell script.

there are 4 different data files containg data for 1day, 7day, 15day

```
LOAD DATA
replace
INTO TABLE T1_1DAY_STG
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'05'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
MM_INTERVAL,
STRATEGY_ID ,         
AGGREGATE_DATE           date "YYYY-MM-DD"
)
INTO TABLE T1_7DAY_STG
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'05'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
 (
 MM_INTERVAL,
 STRATEGY_ID ,         
 AGGREGATE_DATE           date "YYYY-MM-DD"
  )
```

I am planning for shell script like this

```
echo "start SQL loader" >> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
DCTL=$( eval echo \${TX_SQLLDR_${i}_CTL_SP} )
DDATA=$( eval echo \${TX_${i}_DATA_FILE_SP} )
DLOG=$( eval echo \${TX_${i}_DATA_FILE_LOG_SP} )
DBAD=$( eval echo \${TX_${i}_DATA_FILE_BAD_SP} )
DDISCARD=$( eval echo \${TX_${i}_DATA_FILE_DISCARD_SP} )

${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlldr ${ORACLE_USER}/${ORACLE_PASSWD}@${ORACLE_SID}   control=${CTL_DIR}/${DCTL} data=${DATA_DIR}/${DDATA} log=${LOG_DIR}/${DLOG}   bad=${LOG_DIR}/${DBAD} discard=${LOG_DIR}/${DDISCARD} errors=${ERRNUM} direct=true silent=FEEDBACK > ${TMP_LOG_FILE} 2>&1
```

Thanks
Sandy

Comment: Are you loading the files from the server and if so are [external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm) a viable option?

Comment: yes data files were created from netezaa as external table but we need  to load data using sql loader..

Comment: there are 4 different data files containg data for 1day, 7day, 15day LOAD DATA
replace
INTO TABLE T1_1DAY_STG
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'05'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  MM_INTERVAL,
  STRATEGY_ID ,         
  AGGREGATE_DATE           date "YYYY-MM-DD"
)
INTO TABLE T1_7DAY_STG
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'05'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  MM_INTERVAL,
  STRATEGY_ID ,         
  AGGREGATE_DATE           date "YYYY-MM-DD"
)

(
  MM_INTERVAL,
  STRATEGY_ID ,         
  AGGREGATE_DATE           date "YYYY-MM-DD"
)

Comment: something like this from shell                         
DCTL=$( eval echo \${TX_SQLLDR_${i}_CTL_SP} )
DDATA=$( eval echo \${TX_${i}_DATA_FILE_SP} )
DLOG=$( eval echo \${TX_${i}_DATA_FILE_LOG_SP} )
DBAD=$( eval echo \${TX_${i}_DATA_FILE_BAD_SP} )
DDISCARD=$( eval echo \${TX_${i}_DATA_FILE_DISCARD_SP} )
 
${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlldr ${ORACLE_USER}/${ORACLE_PASSWD}@${ORACLE_SID} control=${CTL_DIR}/${DCTL} data=${DATA_DIR}/${DDATA} log=${LOG_DIR}/${DLOG} bad=${LOG_DIR}/${DBAD} discard=${LOG_DIR}/${DDISCARD} errors=${ERRNUM} direct=true silent=FEEDBACK > ${TMP_LOG_FILE} 2>&1

Comment: thanks fedorqui for editing..I was trying to edit but could not do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely look at using external tables, as they have better support for parallel direct path inserts. If you are loading from multiple files and there is some data element in the file that allows you to determine which table the data is going to be loaded into then you can use the following elements for best performance:

1. NOLOGGING -- since you're reloading every day anyway
2. DIRECT PATH -- which you're already doing
3. Parallel read of data files -- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm#i1007483
4. Multitable Insert
5. Parallel Insert
6. No statistics gathering on the loaded table -- lock the table statistics without gathering them and rely on dynamic sampling.

If you absolutely have to use SQL*Loader then consider splitting your data files into multiple smaller files and using parallel direct path sql*loader sessions, but be aware that this means running multiple sql*loader processes.

Comment: Thanks much David. Yes, I have to use sqlloader and as you suggested it will be multiple data file and direct path sql*loader session.Do you think code I have given in my first post will be right way to do it because sql loader will run for "1day" and when it is complete it go for "7day" and so one..there wont be multiple sql*loader processes at the same time. Am i Right?

Comment: I don't think that running all the files through the same SQL*Loader process is going to improve speed. Running them separately and at the same time would be faster if your hardware will support the additional CPU and i/o load. Furthermore, if your hardware will support it splitting each file into multiple parts and loading each as a separate process would be faster.